# Creating light with combining $E$ and $H$ fields

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that light is an electromagnetic wave.
So if we take electric field $E$ and magnetic field $H$, combine them perpendicular to each other, and make them oscillate harmoniously, would it create a light?

Comment: You don't even have to try so hard. Just make an E field that oscillates, and it will produce its own H field with no help from you.

Comment: Agreed, and what's more, the E field doesn't even "produce" the H field as I see it - rather, it directly *implies* the existence of the H field. You can't have one without the other, they're linked, essentially one and the same force.

Comment: It's not that simple. How do you create the E field? How do you create the H field?

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you, but would be produced H perpendicular to E like in light? And will it be possible to see it?

Comment: @YuraHolubeu, In general it's pretty difficult to directly generate E or H fields oscillating at optical frequencies. But you're the one who proposed to independently generate E and H fields --- how were you planning to do this at optical frequencies?

Comment: @ThePhoton yes, may be it would be very hard to create them, but I am now interested in theoretical aspect,  in theory is it possible or not, and if possible, how can we make sure that it is light?

Comment: Yes, if you could somehow make a dipole antenna about 125 nm long, and drive it at 600 THz, you could in principle produce green light. It would work exactly like the antennas that radio stations use all the time to transmit radio waves. Your eyes wouldn't know the difference between a 600 THz wave produced by this antenna and one produced by electron-hole recombination process in a green LED.